# Ignore ID in Attribute Selection

Tags: attributes, weka, data-mining

I have a dataset with an unique id for each instance. Now I am running some Attribute Selection on that dataset. Concrete I use the CfsSubsetEval for selecting the relevant attributes.

The problem is that I don't want to include the id in this attribute selection, but I need it later to write out a .arff File (which should contain the id and the selected attributes).

I found some posts which used the FilteredClassifier. But in my case I want to have something like a FilteredAttributeSelection. Something like an exklusive view on the data for the AttributeSelection Algorithm.

Is there a way solving this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by copying the attribute vector (the ids) before the filter. After selecting the attributes I restore it.